# Illica vs. Today's Language

Tags: word-usage, history

I've been told that the language of the libretti penned by Piave (for Verdi) and Illica (for Puccini) are written in some kind of "old" and "dated" language that no Italian of today can easily understand without training. Is this true?

Comment: Just to be clear: neither Verdi nor Puccini used only one librettist, so I suppose that you want to know in general if opera librettos are understandable for a native speaker. The answer does not change either way. I mention this because one the librettist for Verdi was Arrigo Boito, one of the greatest poets of his generation and a great composer in his own right and it just feels wrong to let him go unmentioned :)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Don't get me started, PLEASE. Can we agree for now that the Italians I've spoken to focused only on Piave and Illica? I know nothing at all about Italian poetry: I don't speak Italian. I know large portions of opera libretti by heart, but that means exactly nothing in this context. And I'm not talking about the opinions of opera aficionados, either: I don't trust them. I'm talking about ordinary people: you know: the kind that buy tickets. Some of them wouldn't know verismo from Mother Goose. Which is why some of them might be objective. That's what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 2):

No that is completely false. While the language is clearly poetic (and so a little "harder" than everyday conversation) and from 150 to 100 years old, it is not substantially different from standard Italian and can be understood by any native speaker.

As a proof I bring myself at the age of 13, when I first went to *La Traviata* and *L'Aida* without having any problem.

This in my experience is valid for all opera librettos at least from Pergolesi onwards (Baroque opera is a slightly different matter because Baroque poets loved playing with the language a bit too much; it is still understandable with a mild effort though).

Moreover a lot of expressions from the librettos of di Piave actually migrated into sayings, somehow similar to what happened to English with Shakespeare. For example *croce e delizia* (to mean that something is both a pleasure and a sorrow) and *i bollenti spiriti* (to mean the impulsiveness, especially of youth), both from the libretto of *La Traviata*.

**EDIT:** To answer the criticism in the comments. Of course the language is a little harder than usual spoken Italian: it is poetry. However I think you are underestimating the capability of the average person. In my experience everyone **can** understand those words and I think it is very dangerous to perpetuate the idea that they need some special training to do so. This myth is in fact part of what pushes people away from even trying. Ok I'll stop here or it becomes a rant; so if you still disagree, downvote away :).

Comment: I disagree strongly, but the question itself is far too generic to admit a precise answer. I am sure many present-day Italians would have a hard time understanding, for instance: *V'entrar con voi pur ora / ed i miei sogni usati / e i bei sogni miei / tosto son dileguati* (and I have picked these lines at random). Even some well-known arias such as *La donna è mobile* can be quite opaque for most people. Try asking someone what *muta* means in *muta d'accento e di pensier* and many will answer *mute*. (to continue)

Comment: I admire you, Denis, but the fact itself that you went at the opera at 13 makes you not exactly an average Italian.

Comment: Italian language itself is not that different, but the competing exigences of meaning, metric and adherence to the music (when it predated the libretto) make the libretto texts distant from everyday Italian.

Comment: There is a well-known essay by Luigi Baldacci, *La musica in italiano: Libretti d'opera dell'Ottocento* about the XIX century libretti and their language. I don't know if it specifically addresses this problem, but it might well worth looking into.

Comment: @DaG: Let me be a bit more specific. In your opinion, is Illica closer to modern Italian than Piave? Would an average Italian have an easier time understanding "Tosca" than "Rigoletto"?

Comment: *Completely false* is quite an exaggeration. A single libretto can have both easy and impossible parts to understand at first hearing, even if the singer has perfect diction. Reading them is another thing.

Comment: @Ricky: By “too generic” I was not referring to specific librettists, but to the fact that a judgement about whether Italians do or do not comprehend such librettoes, in general, is bound to be an opinion-based answer (“I understood them as a child”, “my aunt can't understand a word”...) unless a specific sociolinguistic study on this topic exists.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't talking about understanding them *while being sung*. I always read the librettos before going to the opera, it's just good sense. It's really hard to understand a soprano when she sings at high pitch. Here I'm talking mostly about the *text* of the librettos. That said, I never knew anyone that found the librettos hard to understand (and that includes my grandmother, whose education had been minimal). That said I realize this may be opinion based.

Comment: Also @DaG of course it is poetry, so it is not always as natural as spoken language, but it is just false that the music predates the libretto. If anything it is the other way round (that is the librettist wrote the libretto and then the composer set it to music) and very often composer and librettists worked together playing one off the other.

Comment: Denis, this is why I wrote, textually, “**when** it predated the libretto”. All three cases happened, so I specified the especially unfortunate case, so to say.

Comment: As for myself, I believe on the contrary you greatly overestimate the literacy of Italian people. Almost 60% of Italians cannot be bothered to read even *one* book a year (see [here](http://www.aie.it/Cosafacciamo/Cifreenumeridelleditoria/Mercatoeindaginidisettore.aspx) the reports of the Association of Italian Publishers), not even chick-lit or a recipe book, let alone understand eighteen-century (or earlier) poetry.

Comment: And, while I agree that it might be dangerous to insist too much that a special training is necessary to enjoy art, there is the opposite myth that no particulat effort is needed to really understand what it is about, to fully comprehend the language of music and opera (and other forms of communication), that anybody can express an uninformed opinion about anything.

Comment: @Dag I think we will have to agree to disagree. However a nitpick (sorry I can't resist): here we're talking about late nineteenth to early twentieth century poetry, not eighteenth :). Some of Puccini's operas are less than one hundred years old!

Comment: My bad (or better, my mistyping), Denis!

Comment: @DenisNardin: Let me be a nag, pedant, and pain in the ass all at the same time: I just can't resist: sopranos with marbles in their mouths are one of the worst things ever to happen to opera. It's a whole different issue, and, in my hardly humble opinion, a matter of good taste vs no taste. Wagner struggled with it, and railed against it, throughout his career. I was not at all amused when I heard one soprano state in an interview that she sings her home address when she forgets the "lyrics."

Comment: @Ricky Well, I can't say I am a fan of Sprechgesang (although a slightly better diction would be sometimes appropriate). However the comment tread is a bit long, and this is unrelated to the question, so if you want to discuss it, it may be better to do so in chat

Comment: @DaG: I wonder if the fall of opera's popularity in Italy isn't partly due to this. Opera was never meant to be an elite art to begin with (just like Shakespeare was never meant to be an elite playwright). For years I've been a warm advocate of translating libretti, being firmly convinced (I still am) that understanding the "lyrics" is an extremely important part of the opera experience (Baroque be damned, I'm talking about the "Golden Age" of opera). Some people protest that the music is "connected" to the original text, and severing the link would destroy the whole thing (cont.)

Comment: @DaG: Now it turns out that the "original" text doesn't help those who are expected to understand it either. Thunder and lightning. I'm not a happy camper here.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Stands to reason; I don't like chats, though. I'm in favor of written (or typed) text to remain accessible (for easy retrieval and subsequent quoting) for as long as possible.

Comment: @Ricky (one more comment and then I'll stop) I am honestly surprised by all the downvotes because they go contrary to my experience whenever I managed to convince someone to go to the opera. I really would like to see an answer defending the point of view that an Italian native speaker can't normally understand the libretto of an opera, say by Verdi, because it is just unconceivable for me.

Comment: @DenisNardin: As for appreciating Shakespeare, it's a matter of learning about 1000 new words and expressions, no more. I realize most people today don't want to be bothered; but what can I tell you? Most people today somehow manage to put up with boredom - no opera, no theatre, no books, no painting, no architecture, and no religion. I don't know how they do it, and I wish they'd consider my point of view on the subject, but then again, I'm not exactly an objective person.

Comment: This is especially true because at the time of Verdi and Puccini librettos were written so to be accessible by the general population (the paying public!) and Italian has not changed that much in the intervening time. It would be like to say that a native English speaker cannot normally read Dickens

Comment: @DenisNardin: Most people downvote to show that a) they're superior to you b) you're inferior to them c) they have the power to demonstrate it. This stems from Relativism and the popular and grossly misguided interpretation of equality. We're all equal in the eyes of God, and should be equal in the eyes of the law: no more and no less. Unfortunately, low-lives believe firmly that because they're low-lives, everybody else should be a low-life as well, and if you don't act like one, they'll take every little opportunity, no matter how silly, to take you down a notch. Hubris, you know.

Comment: @Ricky I did not want to comment again, but I have to say that your comment above is a bit harsh. I think that people downvote because they honestly believe my answer to be wrong, and that's what's disheartening.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Wrong or not, you've put time and effort into it. I believe it's wrong too (I'm not quite sure yet), but I upvoted it. It's a question of decency, you know. Disrespecting someone just because you happen to disagree with them is a vile practice.

Comment: A downvote is no disrespect, it's just a disagreement. (and now I'll really shut up).

Comment: @Ricky - Before becoming too apocalyptic (God and the like are kind of off topic here): there is exactly one (1) single downvote to Denis's answer (and none to your question), it is mine, I have explained why I don't agree with him, and we have exchanged our opinions in a quite civil way.

Comment: @Ricky - I do my best not to be silly, don't worry. But you might want to re-read how the up- and down-voting system work in the StackExchange sites.